# Help with parametric equations for lines in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

So for number $4$, I understand that the equation below is for a point as well as a vector, so would it simply just be $(1+(-1), -2+0, 3+5)$ which would simply just be $(0,-2,8)$?

[image]

With number $5$, would this be the same formula? I am pretty sure that it only correlates to a point and a vector, some help with number 5 would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

A line is totally determined by a point and a direction as the images says.

At exercise four, we have
\begin{align*}
L(t) = (1,-2,3) + t(-1,0,5) = (1 - t,-2,3 + 5t)
\end{align*}

Can you finish the exercise five now?

Comment: Thank you, would it be $L(t) = (3,1,0) + t(2,2,3) = (3-t,3, 3t)$?

Comment: No, it should be $L(t) = (3,1,0) + t(2,2,3) = (3 + 2t, 1 + 2t, 3t)$.

Comment: Thank you, is the general formula to follow for the end result $(x1 + y1(t), x2 + y2(t), x3 + y3(t))$?

Comment: Given a point $P = (a,b,c)$ and a direction $d = (u,v,w)$, the corresponding line is given by:

$$L(t) = (a + tu, b + tv, c + tw)$$

Comment: Really quick, with 2 points, could it also be shown like this, where r(t) = P + V (both vectors) which would mean that V = (2-3, 2-1, and 3-0) so the end result would be (3-t, 1+t, 3t)? or would it still just simply be the same formula as you came up with before?

Comment: If you have two points $P$ and $Q$, where $P\neq Q$, the corresponding line passing by them is given as follows:

$$L(t) = P + t(Q - P)$$

where $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at it is that a line is defined by a point it goes through and a direction. A point is not enough, as infinitely-many lines go through a point. A direction is not enough since , equally, infinitely many lines go along a certain direction $t(v_1, v_2, v_3); t=1,2,3..$; just add any vector to it. In your case, (1,-2,3) is the point and the direction is given by $(-1,0,5)$